# jquery datepicker, trying to show selected date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

still new to jquery, so please bear with me.

Once a date is clicked on jquery datepicker, how can I display that date next to the calendar box?

This is what I have so far:

```
                $(function(){
                       $("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: +0 });

        });
```

As far as html, I have:

`<div id="datepicker"></div>`

Out of the things I've tried, it works if the date is displayed inside a "input"
How can i display the date as pure text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a

```
<div id="alternate"></div>
```

next to the datepicker and then add the following:

in the datepicker you can add the onSelect event

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) 
   {
      $('#alternate').text(dateText);
   }
});
```

or you can use

altField: "#alternate",
altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy"

as explained on this page:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#alt-field

Comment: This helped a little but still have issue..

It works if both the datepicker and alternate are "inputs"
but what if both are div's?  I tried making both "div" but then nothing would happen....?

Comment: ah sorry was in class.. but glad you figured it out :).. but it should be possible filling the div on the onselect function..

Comment: here is a jsfiddle with example: http://jsfiddle.net/vEcbz/4/         also you can make ur datepicker into a div.. theres an example here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline , and then u could workaround it by hiding and showing it on click but i guess its better and easier to just use it as a input field.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(a, b) {
        $('#datepicker').val(Date.parse(a).add(1).day().toString('d/M/yyyy')); 
    }
});
```

you can change your [dateformat](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work automatically means when you select a date that should appear in the textfield, ie. in your case, textfield with id ' `datepicker`'. Not sure if you have such textfield.

[jQuery datepicker demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

[another jquery datepicker demo](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePicker.html)

Comment: I don't have a text field, just the datepicker/calendar showing currently.

Comment: Goal is to show selected date next to the calendar.  ultimately I'd like my content to change according to what date is selected.